# Azure/IoT - "HTTP request body must not be empty" on build.ps1 (ExtendedCode 51016)

Tags: powershell, azure, iot

When we run our Microsoft Connected Factory build (via build.ps1) for Microsoft Azure, we run into the error below.

> **FullyQualifiedErrorId:**
>   "Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDeploymentCmdlet".

The job was running previously, but suddenly started to fail today and there are no operational- or build-related changes of which we are aware.

Has anyone seen this error before?  If so, what was the resolution?

The public cloud world is new to me, so forgive me if any of the above terminology is incorrectly used.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

```
17:52:44 New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 5:52:44 PM - Resource Microsoft.Web/certificates 'mycertificatename' failed with 
17:52:44 message '{
17:52:44   "Code": "BadRequest",
17:52:44   "Message": "HTTP request body must not be empty.",
17:52:44   "Target": null,
17:52:44   "Details": [
17:52:44     {
17:52:44       "Message": "HTTP request body must not be empty."
17:52:44     },
17:52:44     {
17:52:44       "Code": "BadRequest"
17:52:44     },
17:52:44     {
17:52:44       "ErrorEntity": {
17:52:44         "ExtendedCode": "51016",
17:52:44         "MessageTemplate": "HTTP request body must not be empty.",
17:52:44         "Parameters": [],
17:52:44         "Code": "BadRequest",
17:52:44         "Message": "HTTP request body must not be empty."
17:52:44       }
17:52:44     }
17:52:44   ],
17:52:44   "Innererror": null
17:52:44 }'
17:52:44 At E:\Path\To\Project\build.ps1:2406 char:21
17:52:44 + ... ArmResult = New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName $sc ...
17:52:44 +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
17:52:44     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
17:52:44     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDep 
17:52:44    loymentCmdlet
```

Comment: All fixed!  There was a bug in the Connected Factory solution.  Once that was resolved, we refreshed our local repository from the Azure IoT Connected Factory Github project and now the error is no longer occurring.

Details here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/8fc94436-7fab-45cd-a126-0e693a0e670e/http-request-body-must-not-be-empty-on-buildps1-extendedcode-51016?forum=azureiothub.